# How can I make a iPython Notebook matplotlib plot look exactly like a Python Script matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have a piece of code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)

plt.subplot(211)
plt.imshow(np.random.random((100, 100)))
plt.subplot(212)
plt.imshow(np.random.random((100, 100)))

plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.1, right=0.9, top=0.9)
cax = plt.axes([0.85, 0.1, 0.075, 0.8])
plt.colorbar(cax=cax)

plt.show()
```

I run it in a iPython Notebook and get the following plot:
[image: iPython Notebook plot]

I run it in a Python script and get the following plot:
[image: Python script plot]

Notice the spacing difference between the first plot and the second.

I want the iPython Notebook to produce the same plot as the Python Script.

I tried to mess around with the following lines:

```
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.1, right=0.9, top=0.9)
cax = plt.axes([0.85, 0.1, 0.075, 0.8])
```

But, the iPython notebook plot would not produce the exact same plot as the Python script plot. How do I go about getting the plots to look exactly the same?

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib by default gives that padding on the image (not sure why exactly, probably for aesthetic), but jupyter notebook removes it before plotting (browsers automatically collapse adjacent whitespace when displaying HTML) and the python terminal doesn't. You can remove it through the terminal by saving the image with a tight boundary box and then using the saved image. Just replace plt.show() with this line:

`plt.savefig('your_image_name.png', bbox_inches='tight')`

I would be interested to know how to remove the whitespace before displaying or saving, since it appears that `plt.tight_layout()` doesn't affect that left margin.

Conversely, you can look more into ensuring that the jupyter notebook doesn't remove your extra whitespace [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11022).